# how to store values of x.y coordinates in different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, image, opencv

Following code returns the values of `x,y` coordinates on mouseclick. I want to store x coordinate in one array `a[10]` and y coordinate in other array `b[10]`.

For this purpose i tried with for loop, but `x,y` coordinate is not shown in array.

How can i store these coordinates in array?

I want to click mouse 10 times on an image and i want to store all 10 coordinates in array.In my code when i click mouse one times, this one x,y coordinate store in array 10 times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int i;int x;int y;
int a[10];int b[10];
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     // Read image from file
     Mat img = imread("G:/qt-program/CA2.jpg");

     //Create a window
     namedWindow("My Window", 1);


     //set the callback function for any mouse event
   setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

     //show the image
     imshow("My Window", img);

     // Wait until user press some key
     waitKey(0);

     return 0;

}


void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{

     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;


            for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

               a[i]=x;
               b[i]=y;

          }
     for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
     cout << a[i] << endl;
     cout << b[i] << endl;
}

    }


}
```

Comment: You store current x and y to all cells in arrays but you need to store in next cell. You can create global var for index of the next cell in arrays.

Comment: So when the mouse is clicked this function will be called. The position of mouse when clicked will be a single point lets say (x, y),  you are running a loop 10 times to store the same x, and y in your arrays.

Comment: I want to click mouse 10 times on an image and  i want to store all 10 coordinates in array.In my code when i click mouse one times, this one x,y coordinate store in array 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are explaining your problem well. If you need exact solution, just replace your `CallBackFunc()` func with this:

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{

    if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;                
        a[i]=x;
        b[i]=y;
        i++;

        if(i==10)        
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            cout << a[i] << endl;
            cout << b[i] << endl;
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (45, 187)
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (103, 98)
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (228, 33)
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (397, 54)
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (479, 117)
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (523, 189)
45
187
103
98
228
33
397
54
479
117
523
189    above function shows a[i] and b[i] like this but i required a[i] ={45,103,228,397,479,523} and b[i]={187,98,33,54,117,189} , is both are same?

Comment: When i call above function as void coordinate(int a[6],int b[6]); in main function then it does not work but when i use a[i] ={45,103,228,397,479,523} and b[i]={187,98,33,54,117,189} like this then code work

Comment: Yes same, just i make it written array a first and then array b. 0 index a and b, 1 index a and be and so on...

Comment: when i call above above function as void coordinate(int a[6],int b[6]); in main function in     coordinate(a,b)
        Data data3(6);
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {

             data3.X[i]=a[i];
             data3.Y[i]=b[i];

         } then it does not work i do not know why? when i use a[i] ={45,103,228,397,479,523} and b[i]={187,98,33,54,117,189} like this then code work why? i want using mouse click a[i] and b[i] directly goes to above main function.but it does not happen .why using mouseclick these coordinate do not directly go to main function

Comment: Is it possible that coordinate is not stored in array like  a[i] ={45,103,228,397,479,523} and b[i]={187,98,33,54,117,189} and only display like this ?

Comment: Yes possible and simple please do some efforts

Answer (score 0):

You store current x and y to all cells in arrays but you need to store in next cell. You can create global var for index of the next cell in arrays i.e. do something like this(pseudocode)

```
int a[10]();
int b[10]();
int nextInd = 0;
...
CallBack(event, x, y, ...) {
  if (...) {
    if (nextInd >= 10) nextInd=0;

    a[nextInd] = x;
    b[nextInd++] = y;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above function shows a[i] and b[i] like this-
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (45, 187) 
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (103, 98) 
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (228, 33) 
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (397, 54) 
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (479, 117) 
Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (523, 189) 
45 187 103 98 228 33 397 54 479 117 523 189
but i required a[i] ={45,103,228,397,479,523} and b[i]={187,98,33,54,117,189} , is both patterns are same?